# CPU parallelization of Mosek solver

Tags: drake

How do I speed up Mosek? I am doing some alternating SDP optimizations (Lyapunov problem), but each time my region of attraction only increases by .01.... so it is very slow.

Perhaps if each iteration could be sped up with parallel processing, it could be better?

One iteration takes about 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Mosek uses multithreading by default and detects the number of cores on the machine unless you overrode it explicitly.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I think Holilnn uses an old version of Mosek (9.2.33) through Drake. Could you confirm if Mosek 9 does multi-thread with SDP on Linux? I thought that the multi-thread feature is recently added in Mosek 10 https://docs.mosek.com/10.0/releasenotes/changes.html very recently, but I might be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @HongkaiDai On linuxaarch64 (ARM) multithreading was only enabled in version 10, but the release for this platform only started in version 9.3 and all was experimental. On linux64x86 and all others the SDP solver was always miltithreaded. So the SDP solver in version 9.2 is multithreaded.

Comment: For a problem that takes 1 to 2 seconds parallelization is unlikely to help a lot. It might even be worthwhile to turn it off. Better single threaded performance is likely the best way to go.